# How can I break line of Picker Items in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker

My problem is as follows, I am passing a large string to one of the Picker items, because of this, the text is not displaying completely on the screen.

I tried to set a fixed width but this solution did not work.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={logo} />
          <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.message}>
              Para que possamos verificar se Sr. (a) está apto (a) para receber o benefício da
              previdência social, por favor, nós informe a categoria do usuário.
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
              <Picker
                style={styles.picker}
                mode="dialog"
                selectedValue={this.state.userCategory}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                  if (itemValue !== '') {
                    this.setState({userCategory: itemValue});
                  }
                }}>
                <Picker.Item
                  color="#979898"
                  label="Por favor, selecione o tipo do benefício..."
                  value=""
                />

                <Picker.Item color="#979898" label={data.categories[0]} value="0" />
                <Picker.Item color="#979898" label={data.categories[1]} value="1" />
                <Picker.Item color="#979898" label={data.categories[2]} value="2" />
              </Picker>
            </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pickerContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    borderColor: '#707070',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  picker: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    color: '#979898',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
});
```

I wish that if the text was larger than the maximum width there would be a line break.

image of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your View component with flexDirection: "row" and your Text component style with flexWrap: "wrap":

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "center" }}>
    <Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1}}>{item.nome}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, this solution not working

Answer (score 0):

Giving fixed width will automatically truncate your text.
Try giving it flex:1 and also text comes with a prop of `numberOfLines` try using that.

Moreover, if you can give padding to text to make it aligned in the view.

`Dont give it fixed width or fixed height`.